# Regex pattern to match an alphabet of letters as well as a list of user-specified special characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I am trying to write a regex to filter a pandas column of sentences I have.

My goal is to capture only english characters like `[a-zA-Z]` but I would also like to allow some special characters such as apostrophes [']. How can I string this all together in pandas to replace all other special characters, numbers, etc. with blank strings `''`?

I'm assuming it's something along the lines of : `df['column1'].replace(to_replace = r'[^a-zA-Z]', value = '', regex = True, inplace = True)` but I'm new to regex and not sure how to include other characters such as apostrophes.

An example I would like to scrub:

`source = 'i believe that's a dog. isn't it?`

`desired_result = 'i believe that's a dog isn't it`

Thanks.

Comment: You can just include characters inside [ ] along with a-zA-Z.

Comment: @rootkonda I don't need to specify any special flags for the # of occurrences or anything? I just want to replace everything that isn't characters or apostrophes. So ```r'[a-zA-Z\']'``` should work? Or even better yet ```r"[a-zA-Z']"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try following solution.

```
import re
line = "i believe that's a dog. isn't it?"
line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", "", line)
print(line)
```

Result:

```
i believe that's a dog isn't it
```

With Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["i believe that's a dog. isn't it?","'test' string"], columns=['P'])
print(df)

#Solution1:
#df['P'] = df['P'].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", "")

#Solution2:
df['P'].replace(to_replace=r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: With ```pandas``` this would suffice, correct? ```total_df['column'].replace(to_replace = r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", value = "", regex = True, inplace = True)```

Comment: This approach will keep outer single apostrophes, like `'cat' is here`.

Comment: @Coldchain9 If my answer is useful, please check mark on the left of answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `extractall` for this, this way you can extract only the words and apostrophes:

```
a = df['source'].str.extractall(r'([ \w\']+)')
df['result'] = a.apply(''.join)
print(df)

                              source                           result
0  i believe that's a dog. isn't it?  i believe that's a dog isn't it
```

Comment: note that \w also matches numbers